# SQL convert time to milliseconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, milliseconds

I have this time-duration: `00:00:23.323`
I want to convert it in sql to milliseconds.

EDIT://
I tried this but it isn't very nice:

```
SELECT  (DATEPART(hh,'12:13:14.123') * 60 * 60 * 1000)
SELECT  (DATEPART(n,'12:13:14.123') * 60 * 1000)
SELECT  (DATEPART(s,'12:13:14.123') * 1000)
SELECT  DATEPART(ms,'12:13:14.123')
```

How does it work?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: what you tried so far

Comment: Which database are you refering??

Comment: Microsoft SQL databse

I tried this:

SELECT  (DATEPART(hh,'12:13:14.123') * 60 * 60 * 1000)
SELECT  (DATEPART(n,'12:13:14.123') * 60 * 1000)
SELECT  (DATEPART(s,'12:13:14.123') * 1000)
SELECT  DATEPART(ms,'12:13:14.123')

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(DATEDIFF_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, '00:00:23.323')
```

Result:

```
23323
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use datepart function. 
like this

```
select DATEPART(MILLISECOND,GETDATE())+DATEPART(second,getdate())*1000
```

Comment: And this is for which dbms product? (No one specified in question, and DATEPART is product specific...)

Answer (score 2):

I got it, it isn't the nice way but it works:

```
SELECT (DATEPART(hh,'00:00:23.323') * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (DATEPART(n,'00:00:23.323') * 60 * 1000) + (DATEPART(s,'00:00:23.323') * 1000) + DATEPART(ms,'00:00:23.323') AS 'DurationInMillis'
```

Comment: The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32602860/1175077) by t-clausen.dk is much better...

Comment: I know the OP's only asking about "time" durations, but for what it's worth, the pattern in @Lingo's solution scales better to durations >= 1 day than @t-clausen.dk's, because `DateDiff` returns an `Int`, which means it tops out at ~24 days worth of milliseconds and ~67 yrs. of seconds.  `DateDiff_Big` (which returns a `BigInt`) is not available prior to SQL Server 2016.